# Convert timestamps to another timezone when timezone is stored in a column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to convert on a `select` statement some UTC timestamps to local but I this conversion should rely on the timezone which is stored at another column. However all `CONVERT_TIMEZONE()`, `TIMEZONE()` and `AT TIME ZONE` Redshift functions seem to rely on hardcoded timezones so they fail.

For example all these are working fine:

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT GETDATE() AS original_ts)
SELECT
    original_ts AS original,
    CONVERT_TIMEZONE('Europe/Amsterdam','UTC',original_ts) AS converted_1,
    TIMEZONE('Europe/Amsterdam',original_ts) AS converted_2,
    original_ts AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Amsterdam' AS converted_3
FROM tmp
;
```

While all these are failing with `[XX000] ERROR: failed to find conversion function from "unknown" to text`:

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT GETDATE() AS original_ts, 'Europe/Amsterdam' AS tz)
SELECT
    original_ts AS original,
    CONVERT_TIMEZONE(tmp.tz,'UTC',original_ts) AS converted_1,
    TIMEZONE(tmp.tz,original_ts) AS converted_2,
    original_ts AT TIME ZONE tmp.tz AS converted_3
FROM tmp
;
```

Really annoying since this one succeeds but it is not helpful enough

```
CONVERT_TIMEZONE((SELECT tz FROM tmp),'UTC',original_ts) AS converted_1
```

Is there any alternative?

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: All of them are failing with "failed to find conversion function from "unknown" to text"

Comment: Just add conversion to varchar and everything will work: 'Europe/Amsterdam'::varchar AS tz

Comment: Finally it is gone! I had only tried to cast it inside the convert functions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Lex_Looter for the solution. Casting to varchar (before the convert function) is fixing it